# How can I make the title above the scrollbar or not in the scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

view of the site:

[image]

I can't change the height of the table(the table is not 100% of the container) and I want to make the tbody height = 100%.

This is the html, I work on angular, typescript and scss:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <!-- TABLE -->
        <div> **(the scrollbar is on this div)**
            <table [dataSource]="aData">
                <!-- Status Column -->
                <ng-container>
                    <th mat-header-cell></th>
                    <td mat-cell>
                        <div class="cell-content"></div>
                        <div class="cell-content center-text">
                    
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Emitter Column -->
                <ng-container>
                    <th mat-header-cell></th>
                    <td mat-cell>
                        <div class="cell-content"></div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
[...]
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns(); sticky: true"></tr>
                <tr
                    mat-row
                    *matRowDef="let document; columns: getDisplayedColumns()"
                    (click)="onClickRow(document)"
                ></tr>
            </table>
```